# How to check status of Peerjs?

Tags: peerjs

Instead of keep tracking all the status change. What I am doing is, so far seems working fine. Can someone please verify?

**ICE Status**

```
peer && peer.id && !peer.disconnected && !peer.destroyed
```

**Data Connection Status**

```
peer && peer.dataChannel && peer.dataChannel.readyState === "open"
```

**Streaming Status**

What is the best way? **I can't figure this out.**